# Can't scrape from a specific website using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to **scrape** from this URL below but it's not brgingging the content I see when I access using a browser (the content from a public customer case/story). I tried also simulating a real browser with headers, but nothing so far. Any tip for me?

URL: https://customers.microsoft.com/en-us/story/767633-asos-retailer-azure-active-directory-m365

```
import requests
main_url = "https://customers.microsoft.com/en-us/story/767633-asos-retailer-azure-active-directory-m365"
result = requests.get(main_url)   
print(result.text)
```

Comment: Can you please show me the error? Cz in my case I can see some content back

Comment: hi @DeepBhatt, It doesn't bring the actual story. This is a public customer story website from Microsoft. I get a lot of content but not the story or the information on the left (metadata about the story).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses an external API to get the data. You just need to make a call on :

```
GET https://customers.microsoft.com/en-us/api/search?key=STORY_KEY
```

`STORY_KEY` is `767633-asos-retailer-azure-active-directory-m365` eg the text after the last slash in the url. You could use a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script like the following :

```
import requests

url = "https://customers.microsoft.com/en-us/story/767633-asos-retailer-azure-active-directory-m365"

r = requests.get(
    "https://customers.microsoft.com/en-us/api/search",
    params = {
        "key": url.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    }
)
document = r.json()["search_document"]

summary = document["story_exec_summary"]
body = document["story_body_text_2"]
quote1 = document["story_quote_carousel"]
quote2 = document["story_quote_carousel_2"]

print(summary)
print(body)
print(quote1)
print(quote2)
```

Note that you would need to search what data you are looking for in the `document` object (videos, body3 etc...)

Comment: Wow!! I think it's working perfectly. Can I ask you how you found this API? thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle certificates properly. It would require additional packages:

```
pip install certifi
pip install urllib3
```

And we need to use different python library, i.e. urllib3

```
python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> import certifi
>>> import urllib3
>>>
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
>>> main_url = "https://customers.microsoft.com/en-us/story/767633-asos-retailer-azure-active-directory-m365"
>>>
>>> r = http.request('GET', main_url)
>>> r.status
200
>>> r.data
```

`>>> open("stories.html", "wb").write(r.data)`

Output:

```
>>> r.data
b'\r\n<!doctype html>\r\n<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">\r\n<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">\r\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\r\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />\r\n    <meta name="description" content="Microsoft customer stories. See how Microsoft tools help companies run their business.">\r\n    <meta name="keywords" content="Microsoft, customers, stories, business, software, tools, services, use case, global, collaboration, vendor, story sear .....
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still don't get the content from the story. I think it's  bringing only the first paragraph.

Comment: Downloaded content matches with page source (right click -> page source), and stories apparently dont appear in the page source. So, my thoughts here are, once you have page source, you need to render page using some library like "beautifulsoup" and determine links which can download the actual story content.

Comment: Thanks for the tip., Hussain, I was able to verify that as well. My question is exactly how to get the actual story content. I'll try to play with this module you mentioned.